# How do professors handle writing dissertations?

Tags: phd

Where do you start with writing a dissertation? I know that it's not difficult if you plan for it, but where would you even start?

Comment: Please be much more precise in what you want to know.

Comment: Usually professors write their dissertations long before becoming professors ;-)

Comment: I won't say that it is easy, even with a plan. It is easier and better to handle if you have a plan, but it is still a big project that takes time and effort.

Comment: Usually you start with finding a problem to work on. But I'm not sure if that answers your question, because it is much too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest an adaptation of the so-called **Feynman algorithm**:

1. Take a sheet of paper and write down the topic at the top.
2. Think very hard.
3. Write down the plan of your dissertation.

Comment: 4. discard. 5. repeat